# Detecting if a URL is a file download

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse, content-disposition

How can I detect if a given URL is a file to be downloaded?

I came across the `content-disposition` header, however it seems that this isn't a part of http 1.1 directly.

Is there a more standard way to detect if the `response` for a `GET` request made to a given `URL` is actually a file to/can be downloaded?

That is the response is not html or json or anything similar, but something like an image, mp3, pdf file etc.?

Comment: What makes you think that Content-Disposition is not "part" of HTTP? See http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml

Comment: @JulianReschke https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt, section 5.5.

Comment: RFC 2616 has been obsoleted two years ago.

Comment: @JulianReschke Are you talking about RFC 6266? I didn't understand that it's part of the standard http now from the language in the RFP. Anyhow I can't rely on the content-disposition being present all the time. So I took a different approach.

Comment: No,I'm talking about RFCs 7230 etc. And whether a header field is part of HTTP does not depend on the protocol spec, but on the IANA header field registry at http://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml

Comment: @JulianReschke Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `content-type` to decide if it's an html file or some other type of file that is on the other end of a given URL.

I'm using the `content-disposition` header content to detect the original file name if it exists since the header isn't available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a transfer protocol - which is a very different thing to hard drive storage layouts. The concept of "file" simply does not exist in HTTP. No more than your computer hard drive contains actual paper-and-cardboard "files" that one would see in an office filing system.

Whatever you may think the HTTP message or URL are saying the response content does not have to come from any computer file, and does not have to be stored in one by the recipient.

The response to any GET message in HTTP can always be "downloaded" by sending another GET request with that same URL (and maybe other headers in the case of HTTP/1.1 variants). That is built into the definition of what a GET message is and has nothing to do with files.

Comment: I was looking for a way to detect what's on the other end of a given URL. For example, google drive's shared file links can't be downloaded directly. The response is html. But I understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Could checking for a file extension be a possibility?  Sorry I can't enlarge on that much without knowing more, but I guess you could consider using PHP to implement this if HTML doesn't have enough functionality?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as straightforward as that :-). Sometimes, there's no filename, or extension information in the headers.